# Why is data_length from information_schema not reflecting real time data length?

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb, amazon-rds

When I was trying to use the following query to get db schema sizes from my remote AWS RDS MySql server, I found that the returned data is not reflecting the real time schema sizes(10% of the real size).

`SELECT table_schema "DB Name",
     ROUND(SUM(data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024, 1) "DB Size in MB" 
FROM information_schema.tables 
GROUP BY table_schema;`

The query is executed right after 32 concurrent `INSERT` statements finished without errors. And those statements wrote around 15GB of data(we use Innodb and the `innodb_buffer_pool_size` has been set to 48GB). And every once a while I query it again, I would return a larger number on DB sizes until it get to the real size.

More interestingly, I have not seen such behavior when having innodb_file_per_table on(there are also other configs that are different). Everytime after the `INSERT` statements finishes, I could query the db sizes with the same query and always get the accurate result.

I was suspecting that maybe at that point I query the sizes, the data are not flushed into disk yet. Could anyone give a more detailed and technical explanation?

Thank you!

Comment: The data is committed to disk before the query completes, so it's not that... but it could be [change buffering](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/glossary.html#glos_change_buffering).

Comment: Tong -- Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  Seeing the number and size of the indexes may lend support to Michael's theory about the Change Buffer.